# How to properly create the Id field on a graphql to be relay compliant?

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay, graphql-js

I am following a relay+graphql tutorial and I cam confused with this code:

```
const GraphQLTodo = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Todo',
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('Todo'),
    text: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.text, 
    },
    complete: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.complete,
    },
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});
```

On the resolve of text and complete field, where does the obj come from? is obj parameter from the query? and also, how do I resolve id from the query? do I do not have to resolve it? for example this is the id field code:

```
id: {
  id: globalIdField('Todo'),
  resolve: (obj) => obj.id, 
}
```

Will the above code work and isn't it redundant? how do I properly create the Id field to be relay compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is the record itself, usually in whatever format you get from your persistent storage. In this case, it's a `Todo` object, with at least two properties: `text` and `complete`. This makes the resolve functions trivial. Resolve functions exist so you can do more complex things like the following:

```
fullName: {
  type: GraphQLString,
  resolve: (obj) => obj.firstName + ' ' + obj.surname,
}
```

For the Relay compliant id, I don't think you need to do anything. `globalIdField` does it for you.

Comment: what do you mean by persistent storage? a database?

Comment: Yeah, a database (SQL or otherwise) is usually where data is stored. In some GraphQL tutorials I've seen that simplified into an in-memory data structure with no persistence. This is usually just a simplification for the tutorial though.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation, helped a lot.